spring boot 3 UUID generation issue
We were using Spring Boot 1.5.6 and Java8 and recently we upgraded to Spring Boot 3.1.6 and Java 17. While we are testing that, we are facing a weird issue of reference UUID creation
Entity RTransactions
@Entity
@Table(name = "RTransactions", indexes = {
        @Index(columnList = "contactid", name = "contactid_index")
})
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class RTransactions {

In Spring Boot 1.5.6 the code looks like this, the rest is the same:
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = RewardsConstants.ID, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(36)")
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    private UUID id;

In Spring Boot 3.x, the code looks like this, the rest is the same:
    @Id
    @UuidGenerator
    @Column(name = RewardsConstants.ID, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(36)")
    private UUID id;

The rest:
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "offerid", referencedColumnName = "offerid", nullable = false)
    private TPOffers tpOffers;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "rid", referencedColumnName = "rewardsid", nullable = false)
    private TPRewards tpRewards;
}

TPOffers Entity:
public class TPOffers {

In Spring Boot 1.5.6, the code looks like this, the rest is the same:
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = RewardsConstants.OFFER_ID, updatable = false, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(36)")
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    private UUID offerId;

In Spring Boot 3.x, the code looks like this, the rest is the same:
    @Id
    @UuidGenerator
    @Column(name = RewardsConstants.OFFER_ID, updatable = false, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(36)")
    private UUID offerId; 
    
}

After all the effort, I see an error. Here, the id mention is not the id (64333734-3234-6231-2d61-3331612d3434) in the URL.
Hibernate: SELECT * FROM RTransaction rt WHERE rt.contactid = ? and rt.offerid = ? and rt.accountid = ? order by rt.createddateutc desc
2024-07-25T15:55:44.677+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Hibernate: select t1_0.offerid,t1_0.adjustpointsflag,t1_0.applicabletier,t1_0.authorityrole,t1_0.correlationid,t1_0.createdby,t1_0.createddateutc,t1_0.externalprizedrawintegrationflag,t1_0.lastmodifiedby,t1_0.lastmodifieddateutc,t1_0.offerenddateutc,t1_0.offername,t1_0.offerreset,t1_0.offerstartdateutc,t1_0.offertype,t1_0.offervolume,t1_0.offervolume_on,t1_0.realtimecommflag from TP_offers t1_0 where t1_0.offerid=?
2024-07-25T15:55:44.680+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] {"logger":"com.Tee.digitalservices.TPplatformapi.handler.TPlusPlatformHandler","level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2024-07-25T20:25:44.680166166+10:00","stack":"org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable to find com.Tee.digitalservices.TPplatformapi.entity.TPOffers with id 64333734-3234-6231-2d61-3331612d3434\n\tat


Please explain the exact problem you're experiencing and how it can be reproduced. You say "Here, the id mention is not the id(64333734-3234-6231-2d61-3331612d3434)", but the id in the log you show is the same, and it can't find that record.

hey thanks for the revert, my issue is i am using offerId(xyz ) to fetch the details via RTransactions entity but when i see in logs it says the offer id is not found but it shows this id 64333734-3234-6231-2d61-3331612d3434(invalid one), however this invalid is no where in my code nor in DB.

Then you need to edit your question and provide a [mre], and provide more details, because I don't understand what you're trying to say. As an aside, did not do a "revert" (that would be restoring your question to an earlier revision), I edited your question to fix typos and formatting issues.
